# Android webview doesn't load the last page when I tap home button

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, resume, android-homebutton

I made a webview app for android on xamarin.

But When I tap Android Home button, it closes the app, and when i open it again, it loads the main page, not the last page.

How to make when i touch my App it resumes the latest page? maybe without loading page again?

Comment: And where do you load the page to begin with? Which lifecycle method?

Answer (score 0):

In your activity override on back press and pass the event to your webview

```
OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // ...
   _webview= (WebView) FindViewById(R.id.webview);
  // ...
}

public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    _webview.GoBack();
}
```

Update as Andrew pointed out that I propably understood your question wrong.
If you want to close the app on backpress and not going back in the web view you have mainly to possibilities:

- Override on backpress and send an intent to show home (your app is not closed and therefore keeps the last activity)
- Always save in the on pause the current url of the webview. if your app is reopened navigate to the persisted website url _webView.LoadUrl(..)

Comment: What does this have to do with saving the WebView's state when the app is backgrounded?

Comment: If I understand the question right, he wants to go back in the webview when pressing back instead of showing the home screen.